# Typscript: return number is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I read out a json File with data and afterwars in the methode total I want to get the total cost. But when I want to calculate it product.price is return undefined. So afterwards the result will be displayed as not a number.

```
{
    "id": "010",
    "productName": "Olivenöl",
    "specialOffer": 14.35,
    "normalPrice": 17.95,
    "imageName": "olivenoel.jpg",
    "description": "Bertolli Olivenöl extra vergine originale",
    "amount": 1
}

get total() {
    let sum: number = 0.0;
    this.products.forEach(product => { 
        console.log(product.price);
        sum += (product.price * product.amount)});
    console.log(sum)
    return sum;
}

export class Product {
id: string;
productName: string;
specialOffer?: number;
normalPrice: number;
imageName: string;
description: string;
amount: number;

get price(): number {
    if(this.hasSpecialOffer) {
        return this.specialOffer;
    } else {
        return this.normalPrice
    }
}

get hasSpecialOffer(): boolean {
    if(this.specialOffer) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}}
```

Comment: How are you reading the file to an object?

Comment: I'm reading it with "return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/products.json', 'utf8')) as Product[];". But this shouldn't be a problem because I can display it on an other site.

Comment: Title says "NotANumber", which would seem to indicate a [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) to me, but then the body mentions getting `undefined`, which, while technically not a number, is nothing close to NaN.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
this.specialOffer?: number;
```

`this.specialOffer` is of type `undefined | number` and can't be assigned to `number`. You can, however, re-write your type guard as such:

```
get price(): number {
  if(this.specialOffer != undefined) {
    return this.specialOffer;
  } else {
    return this.normalPrice
  }
}
```

No need for `hasSpecialOffer` in this writing, by the way.

It TS-compiles without any problem, [see for yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=6&pln=11&pc=5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoQCYCuC8A3gFBlxVwCWeAXHGjFDQHYDmA3JdWLoWIA5FAFtgjZq049qTMMAQ0USAPIAzdcCgB+RmwKiARttnU20USpw0EEuAeOneVGlY7AR4yS3bcXcHjAaAisYDA0EGw+0v5yYhAEbDD6hiZQPAEe8Py2wAAUAJSpTlBw5HJyNOr5MAAWNGgAdGgKSioaWmUAhAC8cElB6uzAeIXlAZXUUMAwBFBscPWNLW3KaprOU1QAvnDASGjAE9uVM3MLSw3NFlBWSDZ2k9Q7Aa87QA).

Comment: I wrote it this way, but it still returns undefined.

Comment: That's because `this.normalPrice` is undefined. As of now, we can't know why because your question is lacking the necessary code to reproduce the problem (that is, by the way, why your question has been closed). I recommend you have TS Playground example that displays your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting this JSON data from some external resource or service.

So you will have to use a constructor here in following way -

```
constructor(data: Product) {
   id: data.id;
   productName: data.productName;
   specialOffer: data.specialOffer;
   normalPrice: data.normalPrice;
   imageName: data.imageName;
   description: data.description
 }
```

You can use loadash also to use _.assign above.

You can pass json data like this -

```
const data = new Product(json);
```

then `data.price()` will give you the result I guess.

Comment: No need for lodash, `Object.assign` can do the same natively